# TemplateDoesNotExist al mostrar una template de otra aplicación en un proyecto Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url, django-urls

Tengo un sitio web con dos applicaciones `dos_website`, que contiene las paginas home y principales, y el blog, que contiene las actualidades:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Work/Dos/webapp$ tree -L 1
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── blog/
├── db.sqlite3
├── dos_website/
├── firstrecord.json
├── firstrecord.txt
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── website/

3 directories, 7 files
```

Me gustaría acceder a la página del blog de mi sitio web cuya dirección se supone que es `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/`:

`webapp/dos_website/templates/dos_website/base.html`

```
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li>
            <a role="button" href="{% url 'blog:all_blogs' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Actualités</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</html>
```

La redirección es gestionada en primer lugar por el archivo `urls.py` de la aplicación web que gestiona esta página:

`webapp/website/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from dos_website import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Home
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

    # blog
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

Y por lo tanto es redirigido al archivo `urls.py` de la aplicación del blog:

`webapp/blog/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_blogs, name='all_blogs'),
]
```

Aquí está mi archivo `views.py` en la aplicación del blog:

`webapp/blog/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def all_blogs(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/all_blogs.html')
```

Sin embargo, tengo un archivo `all_blogs.html` en mi aplicación de blog:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Work/Dos/webapp/blog$ tree -L 3
.
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   └── blog
│       └── all_blogs.html   <-- aqui esta
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dos_website']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\blog\all_blogs.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\blog\all_blogs.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\webapp\dos_website\templates\blog\all_blogs.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\webapp\blog\views.py", line 5, in all_blogs
    return render(request, 'blog/all_blogs.html')
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\Dos\dos_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/
Exception Value: blog/all_blogs.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que la variable `DIRS` en `settings.py` este bien definida, debería decir:

```
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

Y en este caso también puedes agregar el nombre de la app con la que estas trabajando:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app_name', 'templates', 'your_app_name'),
                ...
                ]
    }
]
```

Por último podrías verificar que tu aplicación esté en `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'blog',
    ...
]
```